# LINQ Convert datetime

Tags: linq-to-sql

I wanted to convert this query to LINQ

```
SELECT     AVG(currentvalue) AS ChartAvg, CONVERT(varchar(10), ReceivedDate, 103) AS RecDate
FROM         DatapointValues
WHERE     (CONVERT(varchar(10), ReceivedDate, 103) = '21/04/2011')
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), ReceivedDate, 103)
```

I used the below LINQ but not working,

```
from datapointvalues in db.DatapointValues
where
  Convert.ToString(datapointvalues.ReceivedDate) == "21/04/2011"
group datapointvalues by new {
  Column1 = Convert.ToString(datapointvalues.ReceivedDate)
} into g
select new {
  ChartAvg = (System.Decimal?)g.Average(p => p.currentvalue),
  g.Key.Column1
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working."

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be parsing "21/04/2011" to datetime for comparison instead of otherway around. Something on these lines:

```
        var v = from datapointvalues in db.DatapointValues
                where
                  datapointvalues.ReceivedDate == DateTime.Parse("21/04/2011")
                group datapointvalues by new {
                  Column1 = datapointvalues.ReceivedDate
                } into g
                select new {
                  ChartAvg = (System.Decimal?)g.Average(p => p.currentvalue),
                  g.Key.Column1
                }
```

Based upon your localization settings, `Convert.ToString(datapointvalues.ReceivedDate)` may be returning a different string than you expect.